# Pattern for storing several configuration objects

Tags: javascript

I have several objects that I want to store within an overarching configuration object. The individual objects have various properties in common. I'm used to a functional programming style in JavaScript, but can't figure out a DRY way to implement the storage of these objects in a global config object.

#### Solution 1

```
var config = {};

config['myKey'] = {
  'key': 'myKey',
  'name': 'My Key',
  'icon': '<h1>Category One</h1>',
  'filterFn': function(obj) {
     // function unique to this obj
     return obj;
   },
  'values': function() {
    // function unique to this obj
    return myData.filter(function(val) { return val['myKey']; };
  }
}
```

*Problems: repeats keys ('name', 'icon', etc.) for each object, necessitates changing `myKey` in a few different places*

The `config['myKey']` object assignment repeats for about 5 different objects. These objects have all of the same properties in common.

*There are two noticeable "code smells" with this approach.*

1. One is that I repeat the same property names 5 times (key, name,
   icon, etc.).
2. The second is that I have to repeat "myKey" each time I want to use
   it in the object (e.g., in `config['myKey']['key']` and
   `config['myKey']['values']`.

I know that I could potentially create a function, for example `createMyKeyObject()` and if I passed in arguments. This would save the need to repeat the `myKey` in multiple places, thus solving the second problem. It would look as follows:

#### Solution 2

```
function getMyKey(key, name) {
    
  var filterFn = function(obj) {
    return obj;
  };
    
  var values = data.filter(function(val) { return val[key]; };
    
  config.filters[key] = {
    'key': key,
    'name': name,
    'icon': '<h1>Category One</h1>',
    'filterFn': filterFn,
    'values': values
  };
}
    
getMyKey('myKey', 'My Key');
```

*Problems: repeats keys ('name', 'icon', etc.) for each object, declaring object values in two separate places (function call, inside function), modifies global object inside function*

This solves the second problem of repeating the key and the name, but creates *new* problems. One is that I'd be declaring values pertaining to the same object in two separate places (inside of the function and in the functional call). It's also a more verbose solution. And finally, it has the side-effect of modifying the global `config` object inside of the function.

**Is there a proper solution that gets rid of these "code smells"? Can prototypical inheritance solve this in some way?**

Comment: can you provide sample objects, that try save?

Comment: I didn't include some of the nuances in the functions above, but the object that I *did* include has the same properties as the actual object. Can you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: If it's an issue for you to repeat keys (though it's fairly common in javascript) you might instead do an object for each property and add values using 'myKey' as key, for example names['myKey']='My Key'. Of course it depends on what you actually need to do with these objects. It might be better or worse depending on the situation

Comment: I don't agree that these code smells are, in fact, code smells.

Comment: I agree with @Mathletics this is javascript 101

Comment: Have you looked at how jQuery and jQueryUI do configuration with with simple .extend()?  I'm betting you would like using a similar technique

Comment: @Mathletics Is it a disagreement with my terminology or a disagreement with recognizing this code as problematic?

Comment: I think the 2nd. If you have a lot of common values you can use jQuery.extend or Underscore _.clone to set common values to new configuration objects

Comment: If you want to have a default config and make five variations on that, consider having one default config object and merging in partial config objects to create the five full objects. You can use .extend in jQuery to do this very easily or copy their code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L120

Comment: I'd like to accomplish this without loading in additional library like jQuery or Underscore. Although I do agree that jQuery's .extend method looks to be a viable solution.

Comment: So copy it.  That's the beauty of open source :)

Comment: Looking at the source code now, thanks!

Comment: @Himmel I disagree that this code is problematic. Don't take DRY to an obsessive degree. If you have multiple static objects that define the same keys, it is absolutely OK and even _expected_ that you will repeat those keys for each object. If you replace the object literal with a function that generates the object, well, now you have a bunch of repeated function calls. Is that really better? (Sometimes it is, but my point is to not follow the principle blindly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a constructor, I don't see a need for inheritance

```
function Config(key, name, icon, values, filterFn) {
    this.key = key;
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.values = values;
    this.filterFn = filterFn;
}

var cfg = {};
// Don't want to repeat "someKey"? put it in a variable.
var myKey = 'someKey';
cfg[myKey] = new Config(myKey, 'someName', 'icon', 
                         [1,2], function(obj){ return obj + myKey});
myKey = 'otherKey';
cfg[myKey] = new Config(myKey, 'anotherName', 'anotherIcon',
                         [3,4], function(obj){ return obj + '_' + myKey});

// Or create a method to help, may be overdoing it...
function addConfig(key, name, icon, values, filterFn) {
    cfg[myKey] = new Config(key, name, icon, values, filterFn];
}

addConfig('someKey', 'thatName', 'thisIcon', [6,7], o => o);
```

In EcmaScript 6, you can save some typing

```
function Config(key, name, icon, values, filterFn) {
    Object.assign(this, {key, name, icon, values, filterFn});
}
```

Comment: The ES5 solution still necessitates that I repeat 'someKey' if I want to use it inside one of the functions that are passed in as arguments. In some instances, this means repeating it several times.

Comment: Why? The only place that defines the key is the constructor, you just pass in arguments

Comment: Right, but for example, in your `cfg.someKey` variable assignment, looking at the 5th and final argument, what if I would like to reference `someKey` multiple times *within* that function?

Comment: Create a variable? `var keyName = 'someKey'; cfg[keyName] = new Config(keyName, 'someName', 'icon', [1,2], function(obj){ return obj + keyName});` But yes, if you are referencing the object after you create it, you do have to repeat the key (property/field) names, just like in any other language?

Comment: I realize that this is a viable solution, but I'm looking for one that scales. I'd rather not pollute the global scope with variables outside of my new object declarations. In some cases I would be creating variables for as many as 4 of the properties, all outside of the actual object declaration. Keep in mind that these are not concerns of functionality but rather concision and composition.

Comment: @Himmel Why would you use global variables? Use the module pattern to make sure you only expose what you want. My example uses globals for simplicity because it's not the point of the example. I did add another example that doesn't use globals. Without seeing the real usage, it's hard to come up with an example that works for everything. Forgive me, but I think you may be over-thinking it.

Comment: @Himmel I think an example from a language that does do what you want would help us better understand your question.

Comment: Maybe I am overthinking it, I just assumed there was a better way to create these configuration objects that saved the need to repeat myself. I think using a constructor is probably the best option for my case. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done before:

```
var defaultConfig = {
    everything: 'goes',
    'in': {here: ""},
    once: true
};
var selectedOptions = jQuery.extend(true, {}, defaultConfig, optionConfig);
```

Where optionConfig can look like this:

```
{once: false}
```